# `"${workspaceFolder/*.cpp}" in tasks.json doesn't work

Tags: wildcard

```
    {
      "type": "cppbuild",
      "label": "C/C++: g++ build c++ files",
      "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
      "args": [
        "-std=c++17",
        "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
        "-g",
        "${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp",
        "-o",
        "${workspaceFolder}/build/a.out"
      ],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
      },
      "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      },
    }
```

Until a few days ago, when I set this in the tasks.json file and built, all cpp files in the workspace were built. But now the build is not working and an error like this appears.

clang: error: no such file or directory:

After changing `"${workspaceFolder/*.cpp}"` to  `"${files}"`, and building the open file, if built normally.